# CALayer shadow and translucent UINavigationBars

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, quartz-2d, dropshadow

I've got a translucent navigation bar which is being rendered with a navigation controller.

I'd like to add a drop shadow underneath it, however, when the shadow is rendered, it seems to draw it inside the navigation bar too.

This is quite annoying, and I'd like to render the part of the shadow which is beneath the navigation bar.

Here's the code to render the shadow:

```
    navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];

    navController.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)].CGPath;
    navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0f;
    navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    navController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Here's what I would like to achieve (created in an image editor):
[image]

However, here's what is actually rendered:
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: navController.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
change it may be work

Comment: Doing that would just restrict the shadow within the bounds of the navigation bar, which isn't what I want. I kind of want the opposite of that.

Comment: may be changing the shadowOffset's y value would help; something like navController.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, heightOfNavigationBar);

Comment: http://ioscodesnippet.tumblr.com/post/10437516225/adding-drop-shadow-on-uinavigationbar

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(132.0/255) green:(132.0/255) blue:(132.0/255) alpha:1.0]];
```

Try changing parameters as per your requirements.

Rather I would suggest to go with the linked approach will be beneficial as well as standard.
http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/adding-background-image-uinavigationbar/

source for that :
https://github.com/scelis/ExampleNavBarBackground